# Button in not resized with visible keyboard in layout with stateVisible flag

Tags: java, android, android-layout, autoresize

I have an activity which should display FrameLayout or LinearLayout with some content. There should be a button on the bottom of screen. Both Button and Layout has to be wrapped to something because android allows just one rootview. I have set a "adjustResize" flag via AndroidManifest.xml. This flag should move button from the bottom to the top of soft-keyboard. The problem is that I was not able to achieve this (the button was hidden under the soft-keyboard instead - button doesn't move). The only way how to move the button to the correct position with displayed keyboard is replacing Linear or Frame Layout with ScrollView.

My question is: What is the reason why it does work only with ScrollView? I used this aproach in multiple views already and it always worked even with different kind of view groups. Does somebody have any idea?

This is how my layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/FirebaseUI.WrapperStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--
            Since the TextInputLayouts change size based on whether or not an error
            is showing we use a relative layout to position them absolutely
        -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_layout"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:transitionGroup="true"
            android:transitionName="email_field"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.ErrorText"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.HintText"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                style="@style/FirebaseUI.EditText.EmailField"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_layout"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="112dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.ErrorText"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.HintText">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                style="@style/FirebaseUI.EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="@string/name_hint"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_layout"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="224dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.ErrorText"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.HintText"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/FirebaseUI.EditText.PasswordField"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/create_account_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="336dp"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.BodyText"/>


        <Button
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.Button"
            android:layout_below="@id/create_account_text"
            android:id="@+id/button_create"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/button_text_save"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a marginTop of 336dp in the TextView with the id create_account_text. This is a lot in the most part of the devices, so when the soft keyboard appear, the amount of screen that is shown is smaller then what is necessary for the other views and the 336dp marginTop.

When you add a ScrollView, when the softKeyboard appear the view is scrolled to the bottom, so the button is displayed, but the other stuff don't.

I don't know what your necessity is, but if this 336dp is just to have a blank space in the screen, you can transform your RelativeLayout into a LinearLayout and use layout weight to fill the blank space, so when the keyboard appear, the blank space will be adjusted.

If you need more help please provide screen shots.